# Retornar dados de um JSON ordenando a partir de uma chave

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho um arquivo JSON onde nos registros tenho uma chave que define uma data no seguinte formato: "**aaaammdd**". Preciso retornar os registros existentes neste arquivo mas ordená-los através desta chave. Como seria isso?

**UPDATE:**

este é meu arquivo

```
{
  "241019846088038":{
    "start_time":"20140815",
    "name":"Event 3"
    },
  "244875799004498":{
    "start_time":"20141229",
    "name":"Event 8"
    },
  "288519758006296":{
    "start_time":"20140809",
    "name":"Event 1"
    }      ,
  "576146455831402":{
    "start_time":"20140830",
    "name":"Event 14"
    }
  ,
  "1416493345292145":{
    "start_time":"20140920",
    "name":"Event 2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Você tem algo tipo `{"20140101":{ ... }, "20140102":{ ... }, ...}` e quer retornar uma lista contendo os objetos, essa lista ordenada pela data. É isso?

Comment: Atualizei minha reposta para se adequar ao seu formato de dados. Não mudou quase nada - só tive que acrescentar um critério de ordenação no `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro passo é criar uma lista onde cada par `(chave,valor)` esteja representada por um array:

```
var jsonDecoded = { "241019846088038":{ "start_time":"20140815", "name":"Event 3" }, ... };
var pares = [];

for ( var p in jsonDecoded )
    pares.push([p, jsonDecoded[p]]);

// pares == [ ["241019846088038",{ "start_time":"20140815", "name":"Event 3" }], ... ]
```

Então você pode ordenar essa lista. Por padrão, o JavaScript ordena arrays primeiro olhando o primeiro elemento, depois o segundo, etc. Como datas no formato `aaaammdd` podem ser ordenadas lexicograficamente, <del>não é necessário usar nenhum parâmetro especial no `sort`</del> (*Edit*: de acordo com o update, como a chave é um campo do próprio registro, é necessário sim estabelecer um critério de ordenação de acordo - ainda que esse critério se beneficie do formato utilizado):

```
function compararDatas(a, b) {
    return a[1].start_time < b[1].start_time ? -1 :
           a[1].start_time > b[1].start_time ?  1 : 0;
}
pares.sort(compararDatas);
```

Se quiser, você pode então obter um array só com as chaves, ou só com os valores:

```
var chaves = [];
var valores = [];

for ( var i = 0 ; i < pares.length ; i++ ) {
    chaves[i] = pares[i][0];
    valores[i] = pares[i][1];
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YnTE/2/).

Essa é uma solução usando JavaScript puro. Se tiver acesso a uma biblioteca tipo [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), essa tarefa pode ficar bem mais fácil:

```
var pares = _.pairs(jsonDecoded).sort(compararDatas);
var chaves = _.pluck(pares, 0);
var valores = _.pluck(pares, 1);
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YnTE/3/). Se você só estiver interessado nos valores dos registros (e não nas chaves), então dá pra fazer em uma única linha:

```
var valores = _.chain(jsonDecoded).pairs().sort(compararDatas).pluck(1).value();
```